# How can I bound to a foreground service in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a foreground service I want to bound to that service, I don't know where to put the connection and where to put unbound, which requires the connection. I couldn't find any examples on Google.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current

Button(
    onClick = {
        val idmIntent = Intent(context, IdmService::class.java)
        context.startService(idmIntent)
    }
) {
    Text(text = "Test")
}
```

Comment: Jetpack Compose is a UI framework so you don't want to bind it to a foreground service.